# how can i use 'memusage' command on Centos 7?

Tags: centos, memory, command

When I input `memusage` command to my terminal on Centos7, it will show `bash:memusage: command is not find`.

How can I use this command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `memusage` utility seems to be provided by the `glibc-utils` package on CentOS 7.  I base this on finding it mentioned [in the description of `glibc-utils-2.17-317.el7.x86_64.rpm`](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/glibc-utils-2.17-317.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) on [the CentOS part of the `pkgs.org` site](https://centos.pkgs.org):

```
The glibc-utils package contains memusage, a memory usage profiler,
mtrace, a memory leak tracer and xtrace, a function call tracer
which can be helpful during program debugging.
If unsure if you need this, don't install this package.
```

Install that package with `yum` (or however you usually install packages on your system), and it should provide the `memusage` utility.

Comment: Good catch. FWIW the Debian equivalent package is `libc-devtools`

Comment: Thank you very much@Kusalananda